# Module Not Found: Can't resolve 'http2' when importing firebase-admin

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, firebase-admin

```
        Failed to compile
    ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel.js
    Module not found: Can't resolve 'http2' in '/Users/Michael/Development/Projects/mpsa-ntcs/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

I keep getting this error when importing firebase-admin to my app. I tried updating GRPC, tried downgrading/upgrading node, reinstalled node + npm... everything!!

Anyone know any workarounds for this?

Thanks!

Comment: When posting your question, please copy the text of any code or errors into the question itself rather than linking to images.  This makes it easier to read and search.

Comment: Post some environment details please. Node version, NPM version etc

Comment: And what is the solution? I hate it to find the question I was about to ask, but no answer but "Fixed it..." ...

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need to install the deprecated 'http2' package. Try running:

`npm install http2`

Comment: I wish this had more of an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

I have changed to use yarn. 
Remove
yarn remove firebase-admin
Install again
yarn add firebase
yarn add firebase-admin
yarn add http2 
And my code can work.
I think yarn is better than npm.

Note: http is supported from node version 9.0.0. My Node version is 13.